# How to list files inside a .a file

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I get to know what files are part of my .a file? Which command should I use?

Answer (score 17):

If you didn't strip symbols, you can use `nm` to see the names of the object files (`.o`).

```
$ nm foo.a
foo.a(objectFile1.o):
0000000000000000 T _function1
foo.a(objectFile2.o):
0000000000000000 T _function2
```

This output will differ on different operating systems.  For instance, here is the output of the symbols within `libz.a` on a Ubuntu system:

```
$ nm libz.a | grep ".o:"
adler32.o:
compress.o:
crc32.o:
gzio.o:
uncompr.o:
deflate.o:
trees.o:
zutil.o:
inflate.o:
infback.o:
inftrees.o:
inffast.o:
```

Each of the above 12 .o files were translation units in the original code, compiled with the `-c` option to gcc.  I used `grep` to ignore the countless symbols defined and referenced in each of the object files.  After compilation, these object files were then combined into a static library with `ar`.

`ar` can also extract the object files.  On the same `libz.a`:

```
$ ar xv libz.a 
x - adler32.o
x - compress.o
x - crc32.o
x - gzio.o
x - uncompr.o
x - deflate.o
x - trees.o
x - zutil.o
x - inflate.o
x - infback.o
x - inftrees.o
x - inffast.o
```

The `x` option is for extract and `v` is verbose, which prints the name of the object file as it is extracted.

Comment: This list down all the objects used inside the file as well. What is the command to print just the files inside .a. For instance, .o files inside .a.

Comment: That's exactly what `nm` tells you.  For instance, on my Ubuntu machine: `nm /usr/lib/libz.a | grep ".o:"` returns with 12 `.o` files that comprise `libz.a`.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But using nm my.a | grep ".o:" returns me method calls some of inside .o files but does not list all .o files. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you don't see a `.o` file in the listing, it's not in the archive, or the symbols have been stripped.  I've updated my answer to show listing the object files in the archive as well as extracting all object files from the archive into the working directory.

Answer (score 16):

I think it would be simpler to use `ar` for what it's meant (manipulating archives)

```
ar t foo.a
```

From man page:

> -t List the specified files in the order in which they appear in the archive, each on a separate line.  If no files are specified, all files in the archive are listed.

`man 1 ar` for more info.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the question asks "what __files__" and as we know from debian packages ar can hold any kind of files not just object files.

Comment: Agree, that this should be accepted as best answer. Short and easy command.

Answer (score 0):

This worked with below command:
nm <> | grep ".o" | sed "s/.*(//g" | sed "s/).*//g" | uniq

Comment: Why didn't you accept any answer? IMHO, `ar t foo.a` is good enogh.